# is there any way to disable browser back button after logout in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on codeigniter and when user logout session is destroyed but when user press browser back button it take to the last visit page.

I use javascript:

```
window.history.forward();
```

but it cause effect after login pages too

this is PHP code

```php
$this -> session -> sess_destroy();
        redirect(base_url());
```

Comment: You're not checking `session` on previous page, that's why user can see prev page after back button.

Comment: nope  because when i refresh page it take me to the login page if it is session problem it will take the user to other pages as well

Answer (score 0):

Back button is controlled in the client side and CodeIgniter cannot disable it.
Whatever the page you are seeing on back button is from the browser cache. Easiest way to solve this is to use Cache Headers in the application response.

```
set_header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
```

For the page that you are seeing on back button, add session check in onload() so that if session is already logged out it will redirect to login.

Comment: where i have to add it like in php file code or in javascript?

Comment: You can add it in PHP.

Make it as a utility function and call on response.

        header("Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT");
        header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");

Comment: i have pass it in the php code of logout function but no effect 
please see the code 
   header("Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT");
        header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
         header("Pragma: no-cache");
      $this -> session -> sess_destroy();
       // echo "window.parent.location.href =' home ';
        redirect(base_url());

Comment: Headers need to be there for all the responses, not just in logout function. Basically in the page you are seeing on back button has responses with this header, since it is not in cache it will contact server and since session is invalid it will cause login prompt.

Also session check in onload() (for the page you are seeing on back button) will make sure login is prompted if session is invalidated.

Comment: sorry i didnot get what you want to say